# Mocking static functions from other classes in Java using PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have written test cases for testing a function in class `Main`, called `functionMain()`. I have seen people using PowerMockito to test static functions in the class `Main` which is under test.

But in my case, `functionMain()` is using a static function from another class called `Branch` called `staticBranchFunction()`.

I want to mock `staticBranchFunction()` inside the tests for the `Main` class.

This main function actually has calls to static functions from different classes `Branch1`, `Branch2` etc.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: That actually answers how to test the static methods from the same class that is under test, but not the static functions from different classes.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: yes little bit code will help us understand clear

Comment: are you  testing/invoking functionMain() from junit, and it has call tto other static methos which you want to mock ?

Comment: The main problem here is the use of *static access*. The fact that you have problems to test is is an indication that **code using static access to other classes methods or variables is hard to reuse**. So the better way then surrendering to you bad design y using PowerMock would be to change this other classes method to non-static and *inject* an instances of that other class into your code under test (preferably as a *constructor parameter*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyStatic;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Boom.class})
public class DocTest {

    public String boomWrapper() {
        return Boom.detonate();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBoom() {
        mockStatic(Boom.class);
        when(Boom.detonate()).thenReturn("defused");
        String actual = boomWrapper();
        verifyStatic(Boom.class, times(1));
        Boom.detonate();
        assertEquals("defused", actual);
    }    
}

class Boom {
    private static final String BOOM = "Boom!";  
    public static String detonate() {
        return BOOM;
    }
}
```

### Dependencies:

```
junit:junit:4.12  
org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0  
org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5  
org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5
```

### Description:

For more supported versions, please read: [Mockito + PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions), [other supported frameworks](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Getting-Started#maven-setup)
Requirements:

- List all static classes in `@PrepareForTest({Boom.class})` separate by comma.
- Mock all static classes by `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Boom.class)` separate by comma.
- use regular mockito methods to setup your expectation, for example `Mockito.when(Boom.detonate()).thenReturn("defused")`
- verify behavior by `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Boom.class, Mockito.times(1)); Boom.detonate();` **Important:** You need to call `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Boom.class)` per method verification.

More details on [PowerMock wiki](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method).